# How to install older version of wine?

Tags: wine

I need to install tally in my compaq presario cq40-330tu.i installed wine from the app market
.and installed tally anr tried to launch using wine , it showed "error! out of memory" , on checking other webpages , is i use wine 1.4 version i wont get this error i downloaded it and tried to compile it by trying the following commands in the terminal:
./configure
after processing for some time it showed x development files not found..........
there was no make or makeinstall file in the directory what should i do?

and i am just a begginer and a very new user to linux so brief explanations may confuse me.
i downloaded wine 1.4 from sourceforge.net

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution probably is to install Playonlinux (https://www.playonlinux.com/en/)

Playonlinux installs application in it's own virtual drive where you can set which version of wine you want to use for that application (and easily change it if needed).

How to change wine version in playonlinux: http://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-11075-Change_wine_version.html

Answer (score 0):

Wine is NOT the sort of application where problems are solved by seeking OLDER versions.  I am also unclear what you mean by "app market".  Please take my advice:

1. Open [Ubuntu Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/software-center/)
2. Type wine in the search bar of that center and select "uninstall"
3. Type [winetricks](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks) in the search bar of that center and select install
4. When that has completed also install [play on linux](https://www.playonlinux.com/) (another user recommended this as well and I upvoted it. It's good software and often necessary)
5. Exit the software center
6. Open winetricks which will automatically update it further, and may be time consuming
7. Possibly reboot pc
8. As much as possibly always try winetricks first and then play on linux to install anything. Only try installing without the help they provide if or when they do not offer assistance.